# prevent sql injection in laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-injection

Suppose using raw query I have the following in laravel

```
$a = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = '$var'") );
```

How can I protect our application from SQL injection attacks in this type of cases?

Comment: http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Comment: [This article](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select() method in Illuminate\Database\Connection  has a way to bind our parameters:

```
public function select($query, $bindings = array())
{
    ....
    ....
}
```

so we can pass an array of bindings to the select() method

so

```
$a = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = :var") , array(
   'var' => $var,
 ));
```

Comment: The query string in the example is very wrong - $var is *still* interpolated as a raw string. Also, please add links to documentation/references.